# Programmatically fold code in ACE editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor, bespin

[ACE](http://ace.ajax.org) (Bespin successsor) features code folding. Also, there is an event [changeFold](http://ace.ajax.org/#nav=api&api=edit_session) which fires upon code being folded or unfolded.

**How do I trigger/set code folding from JavaScript?**

I.e. fold up code for function beginning at line N.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

see addfold at https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/edit_session/folding.js#L259
and onFoldWidgetClick https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/edit_session/folding.js#L685 for the usage example

Comment: This pointed me to the right code to look at. Thx. Here is what I now use to fold up code `editor.getSession().foldAll(1, 28);` and to unfold `editor.getSession().unfold(2, true);`.

Comment: There is a problem left: if I immediately `foldAll`, the editor seems to be not yet ready for folding. I workaround by doing `window.setTimeout(function() { editor.getSession().foldAll(1, 28); }, 100);`. Is there an event that fires when the editor is ready for such stuff?

Comment: You can also use it without parameters, like this: foldAll() and unfold() -- to effect all foldable code in the session.

Comment: Would it be also possible to fold code programmatically, without displaying the fold markers? Such a feature would effectively result in hiding the folded text completely.

Comment: It is possible to fold only class and methods but not foldable items inside methods? or just say two levels, ...